# Find the number of arrangements of 3 boys and 3 girls lining up according to their height, same gender must be ascending.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have 3 boys (A,B,C) and 3 girls (X,Y,Z) lining up according to their height.
The rules are:

- A boy on the left must be taller than all boys on his right side.
- A girl on the left must be taller than all girls on her right side.

Following is the order of height of boys/girls:

- A > B > C
- X > Y > Z

Q: How many different arrangements are there?

How about the general cases:

- N boys and N girls.
- More than 2 groups, not just boys/girls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This forum requires that  you edit in what you have tried and where you are stuck . Also, is this a problem devised by you, from a textbook or what ?

Comment: Reads like an interview question... a generalization/ reformulation... let $A = \{A,B, C, X, Y, Z\}$ and we have partial orderings of $A$ inherited from the groups $\leq_G$ and $\leq_B$ such that $C \leq B \leq A$ and $Z \leq Y \leq X$... how many orderings are there that will preserve the relations given by $\leq_B$ and $\leq_G$?

Comment: Imagine that, among the six spots, you temporarily decide to put the boys at locations $2,3,5$. How many such arrangements fit the height restriction? Generalize ...

Comment: How many ways can you put three balls in four buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Since the **sequence** of each gender is predefined, think in terms of combinations rather than permutations

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the hint, true blue anil, I really appreciate your help.

I come up this question myself. And it is related to mutli-thread sync issue I was think of. I though I had solve this problem sometime before, but somehow stuck this time.

For the first question, the answer is: $C_6^2 = 20$.

Second question: $C_{2N}^N$.

Third question, suppose there are K groups, total number of people is N. each group has $r_i$, $i=1,2,...,N$. the total number of arrangement is
$\frac{N!}{\prod r_i!}$

Comment: Good work !  $\;\;$ :)

Comment: You meant to write $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ since choosing which three positions will be occupied by boys determines the order.

Comment: Correct. I used a different notion.